# MInecraft Zombie Children on Chickens

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a small chicken farm and I enjoy playing with aggressive mobs. However I sometimes get a zombie child riding on one of my chickens. I end up having to kill the chicken in the process.

Is there a way to kill the zombie child without killing my chicken?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A clever but slightly expensive way to accomplish this is to throw a Splash Potion of Healing at it.  The chicken will be healed, but because the baby zombie is undead, he will be injured or killed.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your chicken farm isn't lit up bright enough (level 8) to stop spawning. Either that, or there is a break in your walls that is only 1 block tall. Zombie babies can get through those openings without difficulties.

To get the zombie off your chicken simply leave. When the zombie despawns, the chicken won't. Presto - chicken without a rider.